Got NullPointerException when running outside android studio
I am trying to connect to firebase using this code
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(User.getEmail()!!, User.getPassword()!!)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d("Test", "signInWithEmail:success")
                    val user = mAuth.currentUser
                } else {
                    Log.w("Test", "signInWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
                }
            }

        FirebaseUtil.currentUserDetails().set(User).addOnCompleteListener(this){task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d("Test", "Insert data success")
            } else {
                Log.w("Test", "insert data failed", task.exception)
            }
        }

I got no problem when I am running in android studio, but when I run it outside android studio, I got this error
I FirebaseAuth: Logging in as XXXXXX with empty reCAPTCHA token
D NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W System  : Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.AppName, PID: 29784
E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.AppName/com.AppName.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2668)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2729)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1480)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6166)
E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893)
E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:783)
E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E AndroidRuntime:        at com.AppName.utils.FirebaseUtil.currentUserDetails(FirebaseUtil.kt:23)
E AndroidRuntime:        at com.AppName.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:49)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6785)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1147)
E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
E AndroidRuntime:        ... 9 more
I Process : Sending signal. PID: 29784 SIG: 9

this is the part of code mentioned in the error
Main
FirebaseUtil.currentUserDetails().set(User).addOnCompleteListener(this){task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d("Test", "Insert data success")
            } else {
                Log.w("Test", "insert data failed", task.exception)
            }
        }

FirebaseUtil
fun currentUserId(): String? {
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()
    }

fun currentUserDetails(): DocumentReference {
        return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").document((currentUserId())!!)
    }

the User isn't null.
There is no problem with my wifi, and the User value isn't null. Why is this happening?

FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid() shouldn't compile at all, since FirebaseAuth doesn't have a method getUid().  Did you mean to call getCurrentUser() instead?  If you do end up calling that, you should always write code to check it for null instead of using !!, because you have no guarantee that the user will be signed in at any given moment, and especially not when the app first launches.

Don’t use !! unless you are highly experienced and absolutely sure it won’t cause a NullPointerException. Even experienced Android developers probably shouldn’t be using it because there are better alternatives.
